# Web based Google Talk chat notifications sent to my device

Tags: google-talk

When I chat in Google+ through my desktop, my two android devices get the conversations as well. Anyway to stop that from happening? I don't want to necessarily log out of the Apps since I can walk away and I want to still receive messages, but if a conversation is occurring via website, can I have the Apps ignore it?

Comment: I don't think there's really any way for the app to know this. All it sees (I assume) is that you got a message, and it probably has no idea that you responded via the web client.

Comment: I get a notification when I have gmail or google+ chats open sent to my device, but as soon as I continue the conversation in the browser, the notification goes away on my device.

Comment: @RyanConrad: Hm, interesting. I didn't know it would do that (I don't really use Google's chat service).

Comment: @eldarerathis Yeah, each client has a specific ID and I also see the same behavior as Ryan where only the last-used client receives messages.

Comment: yeah, I'm not. I just had a convo with someone on G+ and the entire convo is on my Asus Eee Transformer, with a little notification it's going on..... wait a second. I wonder if the alert is just the initial talk request, and I'm viewing the history of the item... I think that might be it. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Uhm, just clear the alert then close G+ on your phone, then you should see if you get another one for each message.

Comment: Someone write an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the message is initially logged to my phone, and tablet, as Google says "Hey there's a new mmessage fofor you." Once I start in on the convo it only runs on the one device.